# Is there any pitfalls running Tomcat and JBoss on the same server?

Tags: linux, tomcat, jboss

I need to run on my development Linux server an instance of Tomcat v6.0 so I can test the apps I develop. On the same (physical) server, I need to run an instance of hudson-ci. Since Tomcat will be on and off more often than not, I consider running another server (i.e. JBoss AS 6) on a different port for the continuous integration software.

Is there any pitfalls I should be mindful of ahead of time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, just make sure there are no port conflicts (each one will use multiple ports). You should be able to start Tomcat, and then start JBoss, look for errors, fix, repeat.